# Trouble pushing app using cloud foundry. no lib directory found

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

When I try to do a push I get this error.

> RuntimeError: No lib directory found

I checked the buildpack and I can clearly see a lib directory. This is my first question on Stack Overflow so let me know if there is any more information you need to answer this question.

Comment: What is the full `cf push` command you ran and the full output from that?

Comment: posted a response as an answer. my response was too long. Still learning stack overflow sorry. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I have tried both 'cf push'  and   'cf push ' I've also included one where the buildpack was included. The full output is. 
   [ConfigurationUtils]             DEBUG Configuration from /tmp/buildpacks/2ce1ffc46d2e4b74fdc758d85f644207/config/java_main.yml: {"java_main_class"=>nil, "arguments"=>nil}
   [Buildpack]                      ERROR Finalize failed with exception #
   [Buildpack]                      DEBUG Exception # backtrace:
   /tmp/buildpacks/2ce1ffc46d2e4b74fdc758d85f644207/lib/java_buildpack/util/spring_boot_utils.rb:78:in `lib'
   /tmp/buildpacks/2ce1ffc46d2e4b74fdc758d85f644207/lib/java_buildpack/container/java_main.rb:57:in`compile'
   /tmp/buildpacks/2ce1ffc46d2e4b74fdc758d85f644207/lib/java_buildpack/buildpack.rb:73:in `compile'
   /tmp/buildpacks/2ce1ffc46d2e4b74fdc758d85f644207/lib/java_buildpack/buildpack.rb:268:in`with_buildpack'
   /tmp/buildpacks/2ce1ffc46d2e4b74fdc758d85f644207/bin/finalize:27:in `'
   No lib directory found
   Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run finalize script: exit status 1 'code'